# Explicit conversion of parameters in Expression Trees created from MethodInfo

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have the method below which converts a (non-static) `MethodInfo` into a compiled Expression (`Func`) which I can then call.

This works great: I can call it with a method expecting both reference objects and value types.

BUT unlike the original method where I could call a method that had a parameter expecting a `double` and pass it an `int` this compiled expression doesn't support that and throws an `InvalidCastException`.

How do I modify this to support the same type of implicit casting that happens during a normal method call?

Bonus question: should the instanceExp use the `DeclaringType` or the `ReflectedType` from the `MethodInfo`?

```
public Func<object, object[], object> Create(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    var methodParams = methodInfo.GetParameters();
    var arrayParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "array");

    var arguments =
        methodParams.Select((p, i) => Expression.Convert(
            Expression.ArrayAccess(arrayParameter, Expression.Constant(i)), p.ParameterType))
            .Cast<Expression>()
            .ToList();

    var instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "controller");

    var instanceExp = Expression.Convert(instanceParameter, methodInfo.DeclaringType);
    var callExpression = Expression.Call(instanceExp, methodInfo, arguments);

    var bodyExpression = Expression.Convert(callExpression, typeof(object));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object[], object>>(
        bodyExpression, instanceParameter, arrayParameter)
        .Compile();
}
```

--- EDIT

The working solution is:

```
var changeTypeMethod = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ChangeType", new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(TypeCode) });
var arguments =
     methodParams.Select((p, i) =>
         !typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(p.ParameterType)
             // If NOT IConvertible, don't try to convert it
             ? (Expression)Expression.Convert(
                 Expression.ArrayAccess(arrayParameter, Expression.Constant(i)), p.ParameterType)
            :
             // Otherwise add an explicit conversion to the correct type to handle int <--> double etc.
            (Expression)Expression.Convert(
                Expression.Call(changeTypeMethod,
                    Expression.ArrayAccess(arrayParameter, Expression.Constant(i)),
                    Expression.Constant(Type.GetTypeCode(p.ParameterType))),
                p.ParameterType)
        )
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the same as in this piece of C# code:

```
object a = 123;
double b = (double)a; // InvalidCastException
```

The reason is that `a` is an `object`, so in order to make it a `double` the cast must unwrap it, and then transform an `int` to `double`. The language allows the cast to do only one thing - it will either unwrap or transform, but not both. You need to tell the compiler how to do this cast explicitly by telling it that there is an `int` wrapped inside the `object`:

```
double b = (double)((int)a); // Works
```

If you could do the same thing in your LINQ expression, your compiled expression will work as well. However, you may not know the actual type of the parameter at the time you generate your expression, so you may want to go for a different strategy - wire in a call to [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method, which can unwrap and cast at the same time.

Comment: OK, but how do I do that when I don't know that it's an `int` boxed up inside the `object` parameter until later when the `Func` is evaluated? What's the magic expression I need to wrap around the parameter to convert it to its own type (from object) and then to convert that to the necessary parameter type for the call?

Comment: @IanMercer I just realized that, so I updated the answer with the strategy that I remember using in one of my projects in the past.

Comment: I tried changing it as shown but am still getting an `InvalidCastException`. Do you happen to have your code that you could post?

Comment: @IanMercer I wouldn't be able to post that code because I do not own it, but if you post code for the method that you are calling indirectly, and a code that tries calling it through the `Func` produced by `Create`, I could try making it work when I get a chance.